# Replacing fragments on click of button android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create a swappable fragements on my android app

Only half the part of fragment seems to be replacing
screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The xml file for the main is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/contentlayout">
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/header_menufragment"
    class="com.example.www.newapp.header_menu" />
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dynamicfragment"
    class="com.example.www.newapp.mainfragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the whole `dynamicfragment` is supposed to be replaced by `projectfragment` on click of Project button.

```
project.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              getFragmentManager()
                      .beginTransaction()
                      .replace(R.id.dynamicfragment, new projectfragment())
                      .addToBackStack(null)
                      .commit();
         }
     });
```

the `projectfragment` class has

```
public class projectfragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_project, container,false);
    }
   }
```

the layout file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:background="@color/colorDarkRed">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight=".5">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/img3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/imgfile"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly help me solve this issue.

Comment: It's not really clear that it is replacing the half of the fragment, can you share the layouts of two fragments?

Comment: yes I have updated the file you asked

Comment: As per my knowledge, one cannot replace a fragment defined statically in the layout file. surprised by seeing this result..!!!!

Comment: if I dynamically add fragments how can I replace the fragments? like clicking on chat and project and search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace a fragment defined statically in the layout file. You can only replace fragments that you added dynamically via a FragmentTransaction.

Use `FrameLayout` as container and replace `Fragment` inside that.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

On Activity add Fragment same as you do:

```
getFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new projectfragment())
     .addToBackStack(null)
     .commit();
```

For more info refer below link:
[link1](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
[link2](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/replace-fragment.html)

Comment: thanks for the response, i will try ASAP and let you know

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me try this way

```
WishaFriend ff = new WishaFriend();

                                android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                                ft.replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(), ff);
                                ft.commit();
                                dialog.dismiss();
```

try add this

```
ft.replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(), ff);
```